# spring boot remote update fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I'm using spring boot's remote update to update codes from my local STS to the application I deployed on EC2. I have successfully connected to my server but when I modify the code in IDE, I get the following warning message:

> Failed to connect when uploading to http://myurl/.~~spring-boot!~/restart. Upload will be retried in 2 seconds

And this message keeps showing up, while the server side is not restarted and updates were not pushed to the server.

What should I do with this situation?

Comment: Have you verified that DevTools is running in your remote app? It’s log output should tell you

Comment: Hi Andy Wilkinson, I checked and didn't see devtools in the log, so I think you are right and the problem is with devtools not running in remote app. However I followed the reference manual and changed the pom.xml but the devtools is still no running in the remote app, do you know how to configure the devtool?